# iOS Associating Settings with UITableView Item

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, settings, save

I have a `UITableViewController` that has the ability to save each row to a `plist` file. Currently when you press a detail disclosure indicator on the row it opens a separate `UITableViewController` with four static cells in two groups.

At the moment the data in these cells is just being saved in `NSUserDefaults`, but I'd like to be able to save them in a more robust manner (i.e. `plist`) and have each set of settings associated with its own row in the first table view controller.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each of your groups can be saved as an array of dictionaries within your property list.  Within each dictionary (or group), you may include various elements, least of which could be an array which would represent your 'related' items.  This array could be a collection of simple values or even dictionaries themselves if you are working with a more complex set of data.

You may even take it a step further and use CoreData to create a nice relational object model.

Resources:

[Property List Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[Core Data Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)

Comment: Ok, so I have four things to save - username, password, website and location. I've got my app to create a plist, but the saving method doesn't appear to be writing them all to the file - how do I specify to write each of the four things into the plist?